# Компиляция x86 из под x64: cannot find -lmysqlclient_r

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

Чего не хватает для сборки проекта?

```
ldconfig -p  | grep mysql
    libmysqlcppconn.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.7
    libmysqlclient_r.so.16 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.16
    libmysqlclient.so.20 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.20
    libmysqlclient.so.20 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.20
    libmysqlclient.so.18 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18
    libmysqlclient.so.16 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16
    libmysqlclient.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so
    libmysqlclient.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so
```

Содержимое mysql.pro:

```
TARGET = qsqlmysql

SOURCES = main.cpp
OTHER_FILES += mysql.json
include(../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.pri)

PLUGIN_CLASS_NAME = QMYSQLDriverPlugin
include(../qsqldriverbase.pri)

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lmysqlclient_r
```

Далее собираю в x86

```
/home/user/Qt86/5.5/gcc/bin/qmake  mysql.pro
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so when searching for -lmysqlclient_r
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.a when searching for -lmysqlclient_r
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../libmysqlclient_r.so when searching for -lmysqlclient_r
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../libmysqlclient_r.a when searching for -lmysqlclient_r
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so when searching for -lmysqlclient_r
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.a when searching for -lmysqlclient_r
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient_r
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:131: recipe for target '../../../../plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so' failed
make: *** [../../../../plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `cd $QTDIR/5.5/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql`
2. `qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/mysql" "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib/x86_x64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient" mysql.pro`
3. Удалить из `Makefile -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient_r`
4. `make`
5. `make install`